# Access aggregated data using values rather than indexes

Tags: r, aggregate

Using `aggregate`, R creates a list Z that can be indexed on the form `` a$Z$`1.2` ``, where the first number references the corresponding element in X, and likewise for Y. In addition, if X or Y has 10+ elements, the form changes to `` a$Z$`01.02` `` (and assumedly `001.002` for 100+ elements).

Instead of having to index Z with the **zero-padded index value** of X and Y, how can I index with the actual X and Y values instead (eg. `` a$Z$`52.60` ``), which seems much more intuitive!

```
df = data.frame(X=c(50, 52, 50), Y=c(60, 60, 60), Z=c(4, 5, 6))
a = aggregate(Z ~ X + Y, df, c)
str(a)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X: num  50 52
 $ Y: num  60 60
 $ Z:List of 2
  ..$ 1.1: num  4 6
  ..$ 1.2: num 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You easily can do this after `aggregate`:

```
names(a$Z) <- paste(a$X, a$Y, sep=".")
```

Then check it out

```
str(a)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X: num  50 52
 $ Y: num  60 60
 $ Z:List of 2
  ..$ 50.60: num  4 6
  ..$ 52.60: num 5
```

Comment: That's really smooth and intuitive! Too bad R doesn't have an option for this(?), so you have to add this extra line of code every time you aggregate, or create a wrapper function.

Comment: Yeah. I reviewed the help file `aggregate` and didn't see any argument that had this capability.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Try `tapply` instead:

```
ta <- tapply(df[[3]], df[-3], c)

ta[["50", "60"]]
## [1] 4 6

ta[["52", "60"]]
## [1] 5
```

**2) subset** Consider just not using `aggregate` at all and use `subset` to retrieve the values:

```
subset(df, X == 50 & Y == 60)$Z
## [1] 4 6
```

**3) data.table** Subsetting is even easier with data.table:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df, key = "X,Y")
dt[.(50, 60), Z]

## [1] 4 6
```

**Note:** If you are not actually starting with the `df` shown in the question but rather `a` is the result of a series of complex transformations then we can recover `df` like this:

```
df <- tidyr::unnest(a)
```

at which point any of the above could be used.

Comment: Interesting alternative, though the syntax is a bit terse, requiring both double brackets and quotes.

Comment: Added (2) and (3)

Comment: You can use single brackets but then you will get back a one-element list containing the result.

Comment: I run `sapply`, `mapply` and `Map` on Z to create new lists of data with the same indexes, so unless there's some trick I don't know about, `subset` would require two loops for this, which would make for terser code. Nice tip about the library, though I try to stick with base functions unless it's really counter-productive.